# Fatal error when I upload plug-in

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin

When i upload a plug-in, i get the error below. At other plug-ins, i get different fatal error. My release is 1.9.2.3 and I cant upload plug-ins.

Fatal error: Class 'SSTech_Ordertracking_Helper_Data' not found in /home/jellysepeti/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing cache and check again. 
Then check if the file `Data.php` is present inside `app/etc/[local or community]/SSTech/Ordertracking/Helper/` 
Then check if the helper configuration is there in the `app/etc/[local or community]/SSTech/Ordertracking/etc/config.xml` or not.

Answer (score 0):

First try to  clean your cache files in var/cache/* .
 It seems like SSTech/Ordertracking/Helper/Data.php has not been found. Make sûre the file exist

Answer (score 0):

Also check if **Compilation** is enabled and if it is - disable it. You can do this:

1. in the **admin panel -> System -> Tools -> Compilation -> Disable**

or

2. in the files - **includes/config.php** - comment all lines (i.e. `#define...`)